# How to setup WinDbg for debugging a .NET Core crash dump?

Tags: .net-core, windbg

I fire up WinDbg and drag the .dmp into it. I run `.loadby sos coreclr` and get back:

```
The call to LoadLibrary(C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.5\sos) failed, Win32 error 0n126
"The specified module could not be found."
```

I do not have `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.2.5\`folder.  I do have a 2.2.6 folder though.  How can I tell WinDbg to look for the .net core clr in the correct folder?

Comment: You must install the 2.2.5 runtime (not SDK) from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2. Don't expect sos from another version to work.

Comment: @LexLi Any reason why that might be the case?

Comment: "Any reason why that might be the case" is ambiguous. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @LexLi I mean that I never had 2.2.5 runtime installed on this computer.  I went from 2.2.1 to 2.2.6.  Why is it demanding 2.2.5?  Btw, thanks for the tip - I installed 2.2.5 and now I am able to load sos coreclr.

Comment: It really depends on how WinDbg tries to load the SOS extension. From where did you get the dump?

Comment: @LexLi From a production server (Windows Server 2016) where the app crashed.  It does have both 2.2.5 and 2.2.6 installed.

Comment: Then I believe `lmvm coreclr` in WinDbg shows 2.2.5, which means the actual process loads .NET Core 2.2.5 runtime, not 2.2.6.

Comment: @LexLi Shoot.  You are right.  One of the servers in the web farm wasn't updated to 2.2.6.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Installation in cmdshell:**

1. `dotnet tool install -g dotnet-sos`
2. `dotnet-sos install`
3. copy the load command from cmdshell, e.g.

> `.load C:\Users\myuser\.dotnet\sos\sos.dll`

**Execution in WinDbg:**

1. paste load command, e.g.

> `.load C:\Users\myuser\.dotnet\sos\sos.dll`

[Using WinDBG with .NET Core 3](https://www.mode19.net/posts/windbgwithnetcore/)

Comment: Doing so installed SOS for .NET 7. How do I install SOS for all versions, e.g. .NET 5, 6 and 7 at the same time so I can use them all, depending on the app?